# SQL Check the month is in between two dates

Tags: mysql

```sql
SELECT * FROM bookingpoleorder WHERE ((
   YEAR(sDate) = $year AND MONTH(sDate) = $month
) OR (
   YEAR(eDate) = $year AND MONTH(eDate) = $month
))
```

i have a booking table with two dates for example start date and end date. so i need to get report of all booking on a month.below is the query i used. but i am not getting between dates if the date is
`2018-09-12` to `2018-12-12` the booking will only show in 9th month and
12th month not getting in between months

Comment: Have you considered using [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Comment: i need to get per month so i will only provide the month to the query and then the query need to check the between start date and end date if it contains the month it will retrieve the booking

Comment: it might better if you provide a sample result

Answer (score 1):

BETWEEN operator selects values within a given range. The values can be numbers, text, or dates.

```
SELECT * FROM bookingpoleorder 
WHERE sDate BETWEEN '2018-09-12' AND '2018-12-12' 
OR eDate BETWEEN '2018-09-12' AND '2018-12-12'
```

Or using Between

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookingpoleorder
WHERE date_to_compare BETWEEN  sDate AND eDate
```

Comment: You may also need an `ORDER BY` to get results in an orderly fashion

Comment: Oh yes that would be fine

Comment: Where date_to_compare  is the field of the database by which you want to compare sDate and eDate

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookingpoleorder
WHERE CAST($month AS DATE) BETWEEN  CAST(sDate AS DATE) AND CAST(eDate AS DATE)
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21264443)

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on what database you have. If you are using `mysql` then try

```
SELECT * FROM bookingpoleorder WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y')=$year AND DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m') BETWEEN $month1 AND $month2
```

Comment: I will not be providing BETWEEN $month1 AND $month2 these two months instead only the month and year. and in the table there will be two column with sdate and edate if the provided month and year comes between this dates. i need to select that booking. i hope i explained it properly what i need

Answer (score 0):

If `sdate` is starting date and `edate` is ending date and you will provide `$year` as year and `$month` as month, then try:

```
SELECT * FROM bookingpoleorder WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sdate,'%Y') = $year AND DATE_FORMAT(edate,'%Y') = $year AND DATE_FORMAT(sdate,'%m') = $month AND DATE_FORMAT(edate,'%m') = $month
```